# Why do the Canonical Commutation Relations hold in Interacting Theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

The canonical commutation relations for a scalar field theory stating
$$
[\phi(\vec x, t), \partial_t\phi(\vec x', t)] = i \hbar \delta^3(\vec{x} -\vec{x}').\tag{7.4}
$$
Schwartz in Section 7.1 in his book on QFT and SM claims that this holds true even for an interacting lagrangian. Stating

> We will also assume Eqs. (7.3) and (7.4) are still satisfied. This is a natural
> assumption since at any given time the Hilbert space for the interacting theory is the same
> as that of a free theory...  is the equivalent of the canonical commutation relation
> from quantum mechanics: $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}] = i\hbar$. It indicates that a quantity and its time derivative
> are not simultaneously observable – the hallmark of the uncertainty principle.

This is what I was thinking so far:

The canonical commutation relation comes from the correspondence principle by which the possion bracket from the Classical Theory is related to the Commutator. So, if we extra terms in the lagrangian with derivatives of the field, then the conjugate momentum is no longer $\partial_t\phi$ , so the commutator should have a the new conjugate momenta instead of the time derivative.

Also, I initially presumed we can use the interaction picture and encode only the free field time evolution into the fields and the interacting part would cause a time dependence on the operators. But that broke down as further down the line Schwartz used the LSZ Lemma and equated $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu\phi + m^2\phi =\mathcal{L_{int}'[\phi]}$.

Lastly, could someone talk about the statement "Hilbert space remains the same"? Is the Hilbert space characterized by the commutation relations, in the sense that if two spaces had the same Commutation relations they are isomorphic? I used to think for two Hilbert spaces to be the same, their basis had to be linearly related.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/697797/).